# Can StyleGAN be refined without a full training?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, pretrained-models

Can I refine StyleGAN or StyleGAN2 without retraining it for many days, such that its pretrained model is trained to generate only faces similar to a (rather small) set of reference images?

I would like to avoid creating a large dataset and training for many days to weeks, but use the existing model and just bias it towards a set of images.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to apply transfer learning to StyleGAN?

Comment: I think transfer learning means solving another problem. My problem at hand is that I would like to use stylegan to generate images of people that are similar to a given input set (that may or may not be good represented in the pre-trained model). I hope it is possible to use the pre-trained model and train it on a new set without losing too much of the pre-trained weights.